# How does the ratio of an arbitrary sum of indicators and the sum of their conditional expectations converge?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of $\sigma$-algebras and $A_n\in\mathcal{F}_n$ $\forall n$.

Then, if $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{A_k}|\mathcal{F}_{k-1}]\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}\infty$,

$$
\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{A_k}}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{A_k}|\mathcal{F}_{k-1}]}\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}1
$$

Showing this is an exercise in the context of martingale theory, I'm assuming I should be able to identify a martingale somewhere. But I'm struggling to find it, the arbitrariness of the $\sigma$-algebras and the sets stump me.

Any hints towards the solution and, as an extra, general intuition* about it would be much appreciated.

*i.e., if you see it (quickly), what's the more general pattern of the martingale here which may pop up someplace else?

Comment: One martingale that's lurking is $M_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n \Bbb 1_{A_k}-\sum_{k=1}^n \Bbb E[\Bbb 1_{A_k}\mid\mathcal F_{k-1}]$.

Comment: See Theorem 4.5.5 on page 241 [here](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf).

Comment: I seem to fail to show the martingale property w.r.t. its natural filtration. Since this also is not clear to me from your source, @d.k.o.: Is the statement actually only true if $\mathcal(F_n)$ is a filtration instead of any sequence?
Edit: If it's true for any sequence, what's the correct filtration for the martingale?

Comment: @feltshire Note that $\{1_{A_k}-\mathsf{P}(A_k\mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1})\}$ is a martingale difference sequence w.r.t. $\{\mathcal{F}_k\}$.